# Saving remote service passwords securely

Tags: php, security, encryption, passwords

I am planning on implementing a system which is able to connect to several remote services and implement the combined functionalities in one service.

My system will be implemented with php/symfony which will help me manage all user concerning issues. Nevertheless my question is aiming for more general ideas than just the specific implementation.

Here are some of the things i already considered:

## The Idea

Remote passwords and usernames get encrypted symmetrically with AES.
The key for this encryption should be a combination of a salted hash of the local password and a key from the local file system. This has two advantages:

- A rainbow table attack on the remote passwords table is not possible anymore.
- Even an exposed local password would not give away remote passwords.

The key in the local filesystem should not be hardcoded rather than being generated with the installation.

---

The authentication process for the remote services mostly works with a session key which has to be requested with username and password.

The session key can be requested and saved only when the user types in his password, which then can be verified and used to decrypt the passwords and usernames of the remote pages. Each time a session-key expires the user gets a notification to input his password again.

---

The session keys get encrypted with AES as well using an encryption key stored in the local file-system. This too should be generated with the installation. This way an exposed database would not give all session keys away.

## Possible Vulnerabilities

Session keys can be easily decrypted if an attacker has access to database and filesystem.

If the database gets hacked and passwords get found using a brute-force attack. The attacker could possibly decrypt all passwords to the remote pages as well.

## Flaws

It is uncomfortable that the user has to reenter his password on a regular basis.

Sessions can expire quite often. If they expire on a daily basis or even after shorter time periods, the system would not be usable.

When a user forgets his password and has to request a new one, he has to input all his remote credentials as well.

On a new installation all the session keys have to be requested again.

---

---

My question now is if there are techniques to overcome these flaws or even the vulnerabilities of the system. And if from an ethical standpoint I have chosen the right actions to save user data.

Comment: See the answer to [storing a password securely for api](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40328697/451475).

Comment: That is pretty much what I described. The vulnerabilities are mainly what I am interested in.

Comment: Also there are security issues on the other answer as I will describe them there.

Comment: Re vulnerabilities. 1. No DB session keys are used, the 3rd party passwords are encrypted with the users password which is not saved on the server. 2. Brute forcing an AES encrypted password is not practical and by using a random IV for each encryption identical passwords will have different encryptions. The random IV is just prepended to the encrypted password.

Comment: This might be an misunderstanding, the session keys for the api have to be stored for a 24/7 contact between api and server.

Comment: The solution for 24/7 session keys is an HSM. Or see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40284770/451475) for a Poor Man's HSM.

Comment: Is it possible to reopen the question and write all these things in an answer? I think this would help other users to find this solution.