# storing a password securely for api without encrypting it

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I need to store a password in my MySql DB for use with an external company's API.

In my head all passwords should be hashed in a DB in case the website is hacked and the info is leaked onto the internet.  However, if I hash the passwords how do I use them with the API which requires an email address & password to access?

User passwords for my website are hashed, it's the password for the API I'm struggling with.

I would like a relatively simple explanation of what to do with this please, I've read a few posts that seem similar to my question but haven't found an answer.  I'm OK with encrypting passwords.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to store the password in your DB? Could you not keep it in a config file in your app like you are probably doing with your DB connection details?

Comment: I'd also check if the API offers alternative authentication methods, ie by generating a key you can use instead. Then you can use the user/pass authentication on their site to generate/rotate keys in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt the passwords with the user's password which you do not store. That way the passwords are never stored, only transient in RAM while being used.

1. On creation of a user use `password_hash` to save the users hashed password.
2. When the user needs to save a 3rd party password for later use authenticate the user with `password_verify` and then use the user's password to encrypt the 3rd party password and save that. Note that the server does not store the key to the encrypted 3rd party password.
3. When the user wants to login to the 3rd party site he enters his password, it is verified against his hashed password with `password_verify`, the 3rd party password is decrypted with his password and sent to the 3rd party.

Notes:

a. The user's password is not used as the encryption key directly, the encryption function uses a key derivation function such as PBKDF2 to generate the actual encryption key.

b. Both `password_hash` and the encryption key derivation function must have a high work factor, commonly about 100ms.

Another avenue to explore is the encryption schemes password managers use or find an open source password manager implementation you can use—be sure it is  well vetted.

Comment: Important to note when using this is that if the user forgets his password the encrypted data is also gone. And if the user changes his password the data needs to be encrypted with the old password and re-encrypted with the new one.

Comment: Yes, security is by definition a PITA. The key is that if the server has the encryption key an attacker will have the key and have not only the user's password to this site but to several other sites.

Comment: Not sure about it being an actual pita. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Passwords are a PITA to me and 2-factor authentication even more-so. Every time some site makes me create a password I fall into a "Not yet another login/password" rant!

Comment: It is highly likely, that the user will have the same password as on the 3rd party application. When the database gets hijacked it would not even withstand a rainbow table attack checking for this kind of users.Also a dictionary attack on each of the passwords would be pretty fast which will not only give away the 3rd party password but also the password to the main application.

Comment: No, try explaining the in detail: 1. How the same password is creates a vulnerability. 2. How a rainbow table would be employed. Consider that the users password is run through PBKDF2 for a 100ms iteration duration. 3. Each password encryption has a different random IV.

Comment: With different random IVs the rainbow table attack would be impossible indeed.

Comment: Just a general note: 1. A random IV should always be used with CBC encryption. 2. Key derivation with a minimum time cost must be used. I assume both.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your user passwords are encrypted (at least I hope not) as that implies they can be decrypted (which is BAD security practice).  User passwords are generally **hashed** in one-way fashion (for example using [password_hash](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php))

However, with your API password you have a genuine case for encrypting in two-way fashion and not hashing it.  In that case PHP gives you the [openssl_encrypt](https://secure.php.net/openssl_encrypt) and [openssl_decrypt](https://secure.php.net/openssl_decrypt) functions